# Direct database connection vs Web Service, for MySQL+SQL eCommerce integration?

Tags: .net, sql, mysql, web-services

I need to integrate orders from an online eCommerce site (Linux/PHP) into a client-server system (.Net/MSSQL), as well as checking stock levels and products from the client-server side into the eCommerce site. I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086554/best-practice-direct-sql-access-vs-web-service) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530551/direct-acces-database-vs-web-service), but they don't satisfy me.

The MySQL database is not exposed publicly, while the MSSQL database is. I'm pretty sure a XML RPC Web Service (written in .Net) is a good solution, as products and stock can be checked on demand as orders are placed on site. It won't require us opening the MySQL DB publicly either.

- eCommerce site, MySQL - not exposed publicly
- SQL client-server system, SQL - exposed, can connect to it directly

*If we go ahead with the direct connection option, the MySQL DB will be opened up to the public*

I'm pushed into building this as a desktop application that connects to the MySQL database, and read-write to the tables directly to integrate the sales orders and so forth. This requires opening up the MySQL DB.

Am I crazy to think this is a completely wrong approach? I have made my point clear that I'm unhappy about this choice.

I don't have much experience integrating such diverse systems, yet.

I need some more pros & cons to present in the next meetings, to help convince using a XML RPC solution. Are there any good ways to help explain the differences between a web service, vs direct connection, and caveats?

*I'll mark this a community wiki of anyone thinks this necessary*

Comment: You don't specify whether the MySQL is exposed as web service already, or not. If not, to access it through a web service you'd first need to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Abel. The MySQL is not a web service, I want to create the service SQL side, and consume it via the eCommerce site. But I've been tasked with writing it as a desktop app instead, to connect directly to the eCommerce site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end a direct database connection was chosen.

Note this question is 7 months old, and answering myself as per [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519).